# Solve equation including $f(x+c) + f(x)$ for $f(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

How to solve the following equation for $F(x)$?

$$ (1-\alpha)\beta \cdot F(x+c) - \alpha \cdot F(x) = \alpha + (1-\alpha)\beta - {\alpha \cdot \gamma \over x + \phi}$$

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \phi$ are all constant and $\in (0,1)$; $F(x)$ needs to be a $cdf$.

Or more general, is there a formal way to simplify and solve an equation for $f(x)$ of the following form:

$$ f(x+c) + f(x) = g(x)$$ where $g(x)$ is known?

Thank you in advance!